# VB4 app, Jet 3.0

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, jet

I've got an old VB4 app I want to look at to convert/re-write into something maintainable.

I have the source, but of course, nothing to compile it with, and VS2010 doesn't like the vbp and won't open it.

Although it installs, it won't run - failing with an out of memory error.  I want to try an updated version of Jet 3.0, but I can't seem to get the files referenced in this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q151186/

So a few questions:

1) Where is the latest version of Jet 3.0?

2) Is running the app in VB4/5/6 the only viable option to be able to view the forms, designers, etc to convert the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find a version of VB4, or Access 95, then this would come with JET3.

2) Realistically you would need VB4 to have the best chance of opening this.  Try to find someone who has some old MSDN disk sets.

You might try a later version.  The jump from VB4 to 6 might be too much. I imagine it would open but perhaps not run in VB5 as I presume Microsoft looked at people upgrading projects from the immediately prior version.

Comment: Unfortunately all the third-party sites seem to link directly to Microsoft's site.

Comment: You might find that it works with JET 4.0 with a bit of tweaking.  With a bit of looking around and remembering how it worked back then - JET access in VB4 used Remote Data Objects (RDO) or Data Access Objects (DAO) - technologies predating ADO.  However DAO/RDO were supported up until VB6 which used later versions of the JET engine.  I would see whether the JET 4.0 download can be installed.

Comment: I am (was) intimately familiar with VB4/5/6 and DAO.  But I've moved on many years ago and also don't have MSDN at my disposal.  I don't think Jet 4.0 is going to take over the COM ids for 3.0 components.  (And it looks like Jet 4.0 is already up to date on this machine)  But I have a lot of discs in my basement and I'm going to see if I can't step this one up to a level which is reasonable - perhaps using an older Windows VM to get things upgraded...

Comment: Yeah, me too.  I also remember DLL hell - particularly from MDAC issues.  Good Luck!!

Comment: Jet 4 is installed on every copy of Windows, as it's been a component of Windows starting with Windows 2000. I'd recommend seeing if it will work. Jet 3 was a real dog, actually -- full of terrible bugs (which is why it was so quickly superseded by Jet 3.5).

Comment: Don't even think of downloading Jet 4.0 SP8, etc, etc as, like David states, it is included in every version of Windows since Windows 2000.     And it's a similar situation with MDAC/ADO in Windows 2000 and newer.

Comment: Installed VB 6.0 Enterprise Edition from old MSDN DVD from 2000 I had in the basement.  Seems to have upgraded to DAO 2.5/3.51 Compatibility Library (whatever that is) and compiles and runs (on Windows XP VM).  At least it's progress - I've jumped it up two versions!

Comment: The compatibility library is for convesion from Access 2 to A95/A97. It shouldn't be necessary if you're using Jet 3 or later.

Answer (score 2):

1) If at all possible move to Jet 4.0/DAO 3.6 as they have been included in every version of Windows since Windows 2000.   It's not worth your while trying to use an older version of Jet with all the install problems you will likely encounter.   You might have a few syntax changes to make but I doubt they will be that severe.

2) I have no idea about how good or bad the upgrade path is from VB3 to newer versions of VB.  If you don't get an answer here the real long time VB Classic (not VB.NET) experts hang out in http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/topics?hl=en   That said the VB6 IDE works well in Windows 7 once you know about one particular install trick which requires creating a 0 byte msjava.dll file in the Windows directory.

Comment: Installed VB 6.0 Enterprise Edition from old MSDN DVD from 2000 I had in the basement.  Seems to have upgraded to DAO 2.5/3.51 Compatibility Library (whatever that is) and compiles and runs (on Windows XP VM).  At least it's progress - I've jumped it up two versions!

Comment: Excellent.    Now remove that compatibility layer reference and replace it with a reference to DAO 3.6.   You will almost certainly get some places in recordset definitions where "." has to be replaced with "!" (exclamation mark).  There might be some other relatively minor stuff like that but at the end you will be in good shape as far as the DAO stuff goes.

Comment: I should add that when us Access folks converted the database from Access 2.0 to Access 97 we'd see that same reference.  So we got quite used to looking for and changing it.

Comment: ...and we got rid of it as soon as possible.

Comment: That VB4 app might be a conversion from VB3, in which case you will need to change Snapshot/Dynaset/Table to Recordset etc before you change to DAO 3.6

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Where is the latest version of Jet 3.0?
>
> 2) Is running the app in VB4/5/6 the only viable option to be able to
>   view the forms, designers, etc to convert the app?

**1** - I'd try to dig up an old copy of Access (or Office)

**2** - Actually I doubt it'll even work in vb6 (and vb5 might be an adventure), the project upgrade paths weren't very smooth back then, but yes, you're pretty much stuck.  As far as I know there was never anything else that would emulate those designers.

Comment: Installed VB 6.0 Enterprise Edition from old MSDN DVD from 2000 I had in the basement.  Seems to have upgraded to DAO 2.5/3.51 Compatibility Library (whatever that is) and compiles and runs (on Windows XP VM).  At least it's progress - I've jumped it up two versions!

Comment: @Cade haha, good luck in your journey through the way-back machine!  DAO was the precursor to RDO which was the precursor to ADO iirc (but I may have that all wrong, its been a while).